# removing blank lines in htmlText for textarea

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have htmltext as

```
<p>Here is what some pupils told me about how they prepared for and fared in yesterday's preliminary round.</p>
<hr />

<p>"I will stay calm and try my best. If I do not know a word, I will just have to put something down."</p>
<p><strong>some text</strong></p>
<hr />


<p>"I am more confident than last year because I have experience. I read the newspaper and I looked through the dictionary for difficult words and tagged them."</p>
<p><strong>some text</strong></p>
<hr />
```

I am displaying the same as textarea.htmlText .

But the textarea displays the above with too many blank lines in between them. Is there a way i can remove the line breaks in the text? the text is coming as it is from server side.

Comment: How about trying to replace the newlines with empty strings like so: `htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\r?\n/g, "");`

Comment: this is going to remove every line break, i need at least one line break, but if there are more continuously need to remove them.

Comment: Alright, then change the above regex to this `/\r?\n{2,}/g`. This will remove only two or more occurences of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Style the p tag in CSS.
Example:

```
   p{
        line-height:0.5;
    }
```